# Downloading web-based InfoPath Form

Tags: infopath, forms-services

May I know if there are ways to download web-based InfoPath form from a SharePoint Site and view it under a InfoPath Viewer?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily open it in InfoPath client application by selecting `Edit it Microsoft InfoPath` from ECB (list item) menu.

Since InfoPath web-based form is XML document you can also use `SendTo > Download a Copy` from same menu to locally save your form as XML. You can then open saved XML in InfoPath.

However, keep in mind that you need access to xsn template to properly view and edit your form (access to SP where xsn template is published)

Comment: Got your point. Never thought that a web-based InfoPath form can still be able to download by that. Is there anyway to disable the 'Edit in Microsoft InfoPath' link?

Comment: Also, I notice that the above method only apply if the form is created. If the form is the 1st form to be created in the form library, it will be impossible to select 'edit in Microsoft InfoPath', right? - Do let me know if there are still ways to open the InfoPath form even there is no form created currently in the form library.

Comment: I think there is not. You can programatically delete ECB menu items  in general but I don't recommend it.

Comment: (your second comment) You can change `Opening Documents in the Browser` in `Form Library > Advanced settings` to `Open in Client application`

Comment: I do not have the permission to access the Form Library > Advanced settings for another form library, which I am trying to see if I can download their web-based InfoPath form. May I know if there are ways to open web-based InfoPath form in form library that one do not have permission to change settings for the form library?

Comment: I am afraid there is no way you can open new form in InfoPath if settings are 'wrong' and you don't have permissions to alter it.

Comment: Actually I was trying ways to download the web-based InfoPath form given the following scenario: [1] The setting is 'Open in web browser', [2] the library currently contain no form and [3] also the user do not have permission to access the Form Advance settings. - is this possible?